# Android Studio 4.x : how to create class that directly inherits from other class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

On older versions of Android Studio (lower than 4.0) it was possible to create a class that directly inherits from other class. We could also chose the overide methods. And everything appeared directly.

How can we do that now ?

Thanks.

Comment: Java or Kotlin?  you can do that. create a class like EnhancedActivity extends AppCompatActivity . and other classes like MainActivity extends EnhancedActivity. if you use Kotlin, you must make EnhancedActivity open class

Comment: In Java ! Thanks.